# Trying to implement 2 outer joins both with an OR statement. Incorrect Syntax?

Tags: sql, syntax

```
SELECT 
user_id, (TblA)
username, (TblA)
count(TblB.friend1) AS friend1total, (TblB)
count(TblC.friend1) AS messageTotal (TblC)
FROM 
    TblA
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TblB
    (
            ON 
            (TblB.friend1 = TblA.user_id and requeststatus = 0)
            OR 
            (TblB.friend2 = TblA.user_id and requeststatus = 0)
    )
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TblC
        (
            ON 
        (TblC.friend1 = TblA.user_id)
        OR 
        (TblC.friend2 = TblA.user_id)
    )
group by user_id, username
```

My SQL Syntax error is saying - #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(
        ON 
        (TblB.friend1 = TblA.user_id and requeststatus' at line 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now it will be working :

```
SELECT 
user_id, (TblA)
username, (TblA)
count(TblB.friend1) AS friend1total, (TblB)
count(TblC.friend1) AS messageTotal (TblC)
FROM 
    TblA
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TblB
    ON 
    (
            (TblB.friend1 = TblA.user_id and requeststatus = 0)
            OR 
            (TblB.friend2 = TblA.user_id and requeststatus = 0)
    )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TblC
    ON 
    ( 
        (TblC.friend1 = TblA.user_id)
        OR 
        (TblC.friend2 = TblA.user_id)
    )
group by user_id, username
```

i just change your code

```
ON 
    (
            (TblB.friend1 = TblA.user_id and requeststatus = 0)
            OR 
            (TblB.friend2 = TblA.user_id and requeststatus = 0)
    )
```

instead of

```
(
           ON            
           (TblB.friend1 = TblA.user_id and requeststatus = 0)
            OR 
            (TblB.friend2 = TblA.user_id and requeststatus = 0)
    )
```